# After picking image from UIImagePickerController() I try to show a UIAlertViewController() but it does not appear and locks the screen

Tags: ios, swift

After as user picks an image from a photo album, they are prompted to enter a value into a UIAlertController. However, the controller doesn't appear and the screen becomes unclickable.

It's strange as I use the exact same code for when a user takes a photo.

The code works when the self.getVal() method is not called. It works as expected. With logging, there are no errors in the code. Basically it's like the AlertController has been created behind the current viewController view. The screen becomes totally unclickable as it's not been dismissed. (That's my two pence)

See code below:

```
@IBAction func addBarButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Camera or Existing Photo", message: "Take a photo with the camera, or use an existing photo on your device.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.presentCamera()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.presentPhotos()
    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func presentPhotos(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func presentCamera() {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false

        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera || picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum)
    {
        let myImageName = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let imagePath = ImageHelperService.fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)

        if ImageHelperService.saveImage(image, path: imagePath) {

            // TODO:
            // Error: This right here, when removed it runs and dismisses and updates fine, just the alertcontroller never appears so can never be dismissed
            self.getVal()

            while(!self.alertViewDismissed) {
                NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))

            }

            let success = DataOperationsService().SaveThingyMaBob(myImageName, value: self.alertViewValue!, bar: self.bar!)            
            if success {

                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.doChart()

            } else {
                // TODO: Handle error
                debugPrint("Error, save failed")
            }

        } else {
            print("image save failed")
        }        
    }
}

func getVal() {
    self.alertViewDismissed = false

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter a value", message: "val", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.text = ""
        textField.keyboardType = .DecimalPad
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Skip")
        self.alertViewValue = nil
        self.alertViewDismissed = true
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default , handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
        self.alertViewValue = UtilitiesService.textFieldUnwrapToDouble(textField.text!)
        self.alertViewDismissed = true

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) is the issue? Have you tried placing your code inside the completion block for dismissViewControllerAnimated?

Comment: I tried calling the `self.getVal()` from there, but I will try the entire code block :)

Comment: @JeremyHerrero bit of progress, the AlertController now shows, but it is not intractable, I cannot dismiss, submit or even click the text field to enter text. I'll try to debug further :)

Comment: Just for kicks you could try *self.performSelector(#selector(getVal), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1)*. If the delay helps, then there might be a clue there.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid, I'm just attempting to set `alert.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint setup? It's possible your code is hanging somewhere. http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSyJ1.png

Comment: Nope just cleared them all, no break points I'm afraid. The strangest part is it works when the user picks the picture with the camera.

Comment: Doing some debugging I think this might be a threading issue

Comment: If it is threading, this should do the trick: https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/

Comment: So I just double checked that and everything is running on the main thread... hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by placing the call to the `UIAlertController` before picking the image.

This isn't an exact fix, but more of a workaround if you can be flexible as to what you show first.